# Symfony API, Reactjs and Nginx: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in production

Tags: reactjs, symfony, nginx, symfony4

I have two app running on nginx server: My Symfony API: https://dev-api******.com and my React App: https://dev-front******.com

I'm using a jwt authentication but i'm not able to connect to my API because of cors policy.
It's also not working with nelmio cors bundle but there is no problem with Postman.

My nelmio cors config:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
```

My nginx config:

```
  location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      #
      # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
      #
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
      #
      # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
      #
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }
```

What my browser display:

```
Request Headers:
:authority: dev-api******.com
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /api/1.0/login_check
:scheme: https
accept: */ *
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers: content-type
access-control-request-method: POST
origin: https://dev-front******.com
referer: https://dev-front******.com
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my nginx config and now I have a 404 error

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name dev-api*******.com;
  root /var/www/project/current/public;

  location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      #
      # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
      #
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
      #
      # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
      #
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  # DEV
  # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
  # In production, don't include this and don't deploy index_dev.php or config.php
  location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
    # current version of your application, you should pass the real
    # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
    # FPM.
    # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
    # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
    # for more information).
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
    # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
    # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
    internal;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name dev-api******.com;
  root /var/www/project/current/public;

  ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout   10m;
  ssl_ciphers       HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) { 
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://dev-front******.com' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;

      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }
  if ($request_method = POST) {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://dev-front******.com' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    }
    if ($request_method = GET) {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://dev-front******.com' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    } 
  }

  location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
    # current version of your application, you should pass the real
    # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
    # FPM.
    # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
    # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
    # for more information).
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
    # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
    # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
    internal;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/project_ssl_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/project_ssl_access.log;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev-api******.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev-api******.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```